# Symfony 5: Translate form errors

Tags: forms, symfony, message, translate, symfony-translator

the website I work on was developped in french(FR) and I recently developped the multilingual aspect to translate the website in english(EN), for this, I used the translator bundle. Here are my configs files :

[translation.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQuL7.png)

[services.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dgxi.png)

I also created a **messages.en.xlf** file with all my customs messages translated from french to english, and it works.
Here is my problem : I want to translate all the default form errors.

[My form with default locale: FR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BIwu.png)

[My form with default locale EN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbgoH.png)

The language change has been detected and the tittle has been translated. But my error message is still the same. 
What can I do about it ? Do I have to manually translate all the displayed messages with some JS ? 
Thankx.

Answer (score 1):

This validation and error messages come from HTML5 and language is based on your browser settings.

If you want to force english try adding this into your template:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en">
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you're doing right. It's juste because this is not a Symfony message, so you can't translate it.

This message come from your browser. Only displayed when an input has `required` attribute.